# Javascript to Get Month/Year WITHOUT Alert Popup

Tags: javascript

Found this code that generates a future date just like I need. But it only show it via a pop up. How can I get it to display automatically on my webpage, versus a popup.

```
<script>
var days = 300;
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
alert ( date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getFullYear() ) ;

</script>
```

Comment: Set the contents of a DOM element to the string instead of alerting.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Comment: @Amy But this could be stated better.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this

```js
var days = 300;
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: FWIW I suspect the downvote is due to answering a relatively poor question.